# Checkbox and checkbox text not in same line android

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a problem with text that comes with check box control. Here is an image

[image]

I like text Remember me to come in same line with the box.

Comment: Try adding gravity to the check box to `center_horizontal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout `xml`, you just add a `CheckBox` such that:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/RememberMeCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Remember me" />
```

It should be in the same line.